# How to 'import' only setter to update state - Recoil

Tags: reactjs

I have following piece of recoil code:

```js
export const UserName = atom({
    key: 'username',
    default: ''
})
```

Example component:

```js
const [username, setUsername] = useRecoilState(UserName)

const doSomethingOnClick = () => {
  setUsername('coolName')
}
```

Here is my question. I never use `username` value in my example component, I am only using setter function. So how can I 'import' `setUsername` - only setter function without previous state

Answer (score 3):

according [to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) of destructuring, you can ignore some elements of array:

```
const [, setUsername] = useRecoilState(UserName)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can import `useSetRecoilState` and use it as setter

```
const setUsername = useSetRecoilState(UserName)
```